# C free() double free or corruption (global array)

Tags: c, malloc, free

Here is a struct in header-file:

```
typedef struct Missile {
    int id;
    Model *model;
    Point3D coords;
    int counter;
    float speed;
    float yaw;
    float pitch;
    float roll;
} Missile;
```

and here is code from C-file:

```
#define INIT_MISSILE_ARRAY_SIZE 4

/* An array to keep track of all missiles created (fired) */
static Missile *missiles[INIT_MISSILE_ARRAY_SIZE];

/* This keeps track of the array missiles' size */
int currentArraySize = INIT_MISSILE_ARRAY_SIZE;

int numOfMissiles = 0;

Missile *CreateMissile()
{
    if (numOfMissiles < currentArraySize)
    {
        Missile *missile = malloc(sizeof(Missile));
        missile->model = LoadModelPlus("rocket1.obj");
        missile->counter = 0;
        missile->speed = 0.00;
        missile->yaw = 0.00;
        missile->pitch = 0.00;
        missile->roll = 0.00;
        missile->id = numOfMissiles;
        missiles[numOfMissiles] = missile;
        numOfMissiles++;
        printf("Missile created, numOfMissiles: %d\n", numOfMissiles);
        return missile;
    }
    printf("Too many missiles fired already.\n");
    return NULL;
}

void DeleteMissile(Missile *missile)
{
    free(missile);
}
```

gives me this error: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x000000000234f5d0 
when the function `DeleteMissile(Missile *missile)` is called. I have tried replacing `free(missile);` with `free(missiles[missile->id]);`, which finds the (same) missile in the global array of missiles and calls `free()` on that one, and this gives me the same error. The function `LoadModelPlus()` uses malloc for the `missile->model`.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The code you have posted looks fine so the error is probably in the code that calls it. Can you post a small example which uses this code and demonstrates the error please?

Comment: Your code will have memory leak: you don't free memory used by `missile->model`. As for "double free" it's possible that somewhere you try to `free()` already free'd memory. Try to add in function `DeleteMissile` after both `free()` this: `*missile = NULL`. And change in argument: `*missile` to `**missile`.

Comment: We need to see the calling code.  That and the function definition is all that really matters.  It may not be a double free at all; you may be trouncing on heap memory somewhere and that only comes to light when you call `free`.  May be a good idea to show us `LoadModelPlus` as well.